# Issue converting ICO to PNG using PHP

Tags: php, png, favicon, ico

### Context: Favicons

I am writing a WordPress plugin to download favicons and also convert them to png:

[image] http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/wp-favicons/trunk ( GPL2)

### Icon Lib

- I needed to have an ICO to PNG conversion Library that does not read files from disk but from strings.
- I also need broad support for users so not a compiled php with a parameter that not most of the general WordPress users have
- I am currently using this one: http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2369-PHP-Extract-graphics-from-ico-files-into-PNG-images.html

### Problem

In 1 out of 5.000 icons (the others work ok...) a problem occurs with the XOR functionality. See line 296 here: [image] http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/wp-favicons/trunk/plugins/filters/inc/class.ico.php (Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 64) So the string expected is too small.

### Example

An example is this icon: [click here to see](http://www.slatch.com/media/bcr.ICO) (navigates to slatch.com)

### Question

Does anybody know how to fix this? OR knows another good PHP Icon Class that lets me read .ico (all sorts of) via get_as_string instead of get_from_file which is better?

### PS

I already read:

- [image] [How to convert .ICO to .PNG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37590/how-to-convert-ico-to-png) (tools)
- [image] [Convert png file to ico with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628114/convert-png-file-to-ico-with-php)
- [image] [Favicon to PNG in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584895/favicon-to-png-in-php/5373239)

Comment: I've updated your question title and tagging to hopefully attract more attention.  Can you post more example favicons?

Comment: Is a solution using the GD library acceptable?

Comment: When it fails the XOR op, it means that it's a PNG file already. Just save it as such.

Comment: Is it a possibility that the file itself is corrupted? I tried multiple tools and none of them were able to open the file. Browser shows it though... But may be because it just gracefully handles corruption, or something...

Answer (score 2):

The example icon you posted is monochrome (1 BPP). Its possible the library does not support such a low color depth.

Answer (score 2):

I've written a fully unit tested package for reading .ico files which supports 1bpp images (as well as embedded PNGs) - it's available here https://github.com/lordelph/icofileloader

The link to the problem .ico in the question is dead, but I'm happy to fix the package if anyone comes across a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

@edelwater

I might be mistaken, but isn't the new generation of ICO files really PNG's with a different extension?  That's how I have created them in the past.  I could understand converting other formats like jpeg to png and then changing the extension.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#Standardization

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_(file_format)#PNG_format

This isn't meant to be a answer but a reference.

Comment: ICO is not always PNG format. Most browsers support using multiple image format types used for a favicon (with .ico extension), but ICO is its own image format. This adds ambiguity to the op's issue as the icons he is downloding could be of many formats.

Comment: yes... there are many different icons out there not only the new generation with the embedded PNG.

Comment: You would have to read the head of the file to see if it's an ico, png, of gif. (I don't think anyone would use a jpg as a ico.) and I'm really sure it's not supported.

Answer (score 0):

The class supports 1 bpp (monochrome) ico files.  However there is a bug with it.  It fails to account for the padding of each image line to a 4 byte (32 bit) boundary, hence icons less wide than 32 pixels are not properly decoded.

I'm going to fix this for my own use, but I'm not sure what to do with it.  Post a patch here?

Comment: You would be better off submitting the patch to the plugin authors (possibly via their Trac linked in the OP), then maybe linking to that from here.

Comment: Hi Ian, great, never came to it, if you posted the updated lib somewhere I will replace the lib in my app